# multiprocessing.Pool(processes=0) not allowed?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In a parallelized script I would like to keep the ability to do the processing in a single CPU. In order to do that it seems that I need to duplicate the code that iterates over the results:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import multiprocessing

# argparsed parameters:
num_cpus = 1
input_filename = 'file.txt'

def worker(line):
    '''Do something with a line'''
    # dummy processing that requires some CPU time
    for x in range(1000000):
        line.split()
    return line.split()

def data_iter(filename):
    '''iterate over the data records'''
    with open(filename) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (num_cpus >= 2):
        with multiprocessing.Pool( processes = num_cpus - 1 ) as pool:
            for result in pool.imap(worker, data_iter(input_filename)):
                # dummy post-processing (copy#1)
                print(' '.join(result))
    else:
        for line in data_iter(input_filename):
            result = worker(line)
            # dummy post-processing (copy#2)
            print(' '.join(result))
```

<sup>**note:** you can use any text file with multiple lines for testing the code.</sup>

**Is there a valid reason for `multiprocessing.Pool` not allowing `processes = 0`?**

---

###### POSTSCRIPT

I though of one plausible "technical" reason for not allowing it:

The worker processes in the Pool can't modify the environment of the main program, which wouldn't be true if the worker function is run without spawning a new process.

Comment: What are you actually expecting from a process pool without any process?

Comment: To call the worker function without firing a new process, that would allow to run the program with a single CPU

Comment: `processes` can be thought of as the number to CPUs to use.  Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#multiprocessing.pool.Pool): “processes is the number of worker processes to use. If processes is None then the number returned by `os.cpu_count()` is used.”  Therefore, must be at least 1.

Comment: As @S3DEV states, what you are after does not exist in the library. If you specify `processes=1`, it will still create a new process. You can see this in the library code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55c99d97e14/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L305

Comment: you will need an alternate code path that does not use `multiprocessing` if you wish to avoid spawning even a single worker process.

Comment: Obviously, if you on'y want to use one CPU, don't involve `multiprocessing`.  Just do `map(worker, data_iter(input_filename))`.  Also note, of course, that even running `multiprocessing.Pool` with `processes = 10` works just fine on a single CPU machine.

Comment: Why not propose it to the "Python standards committee" (or whatever they call themselves - I'm far from being an expert). Seems useful to me, and would indeed keep your code simple.

Comment: python's multiprocessing module is a low level module, that you are supposed to build your code around, you can simply inherit it the `Pool` class and modify its functionality to your liking, but making an alternative `if processes=0 then it monkey patches all the pool functions with their alternatives from itertools` seems far too stretched for  a low level API, i can see this being done for `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` which is a high level API but not the multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for not allowing `multiprocessing.Pool(processes=0)` is that a process pool with no processes in it cannot do any work.  Such an object is surprising and generally unwanted.

While it is true that `processes=1` will spawn another process, it *barely* uses more than one CPU, because the main process will just sit and wait for the worker process to complete.  It's possible to imagine optimizing `processes=1` to have no overhead vs your custom code, but it would still be `processes=1` not `processes=0`.  There's got to be some process to run it on.

If avoiding that small overhead of waiting for the pool is important, then the solution is to extract a small interface that can be implemented by both the in-process and pooled versions.  In this case, that's the interface of `builtins.map`.

Then at runtime, you decide which implementation to use.

```py
def mp_output(worker, my_iter):
    with multiprocessing.Pool( processes = num_cpus - 1 ) as pool:
        yield from pool.imap(worker, my_iter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mapper = mp_output if num_cpus >= 2 else map
    for result in mapper(worker, data_iter(input_filename)):
        print(' '.join(result))
```

If you can rely on the fact that you're doing pool.imap from the main function, you don't even need mp_output.  You can just use

```py
    mapper = multiprocessing.Pool(
        processes=num_cpus - 1).map if num_cpus >= 2 else map
```

All the context manager exit does is invoke `terminate`, but being garbage-collected will also invoke `terminate`.

P.S. This approach can work with objects as well as functions, and is a version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't really agree with "`_processes=1` [...] barely uses more than one CPU_". In my real code the `__main__` computes some stats while iterating over the results, so the total CPU usage with a single worker is about 160%: 40% (main program) + 20% (multiprocessing overhead) + 100% (worker process).

Comment: Thanks for the extra information.  With your example, the I observe the main thread taking between 2.7 - 19 CPU, which is larger than I expected.  I should have tested that before assuming the overhead was minimal.  I'm not clear on whether the 40% is extra computation or not.  It sounds like it would happen whether you are doing multiprocessing or not.  if the concern is minimizing the number of CPU cycles used at a given time, perhaps it could be deferred until the multiprocessing is complete.

Comment: The main program in the sample code doesn't do much; my real code populates some dictionaries and calculates a few stats on the results, on-the-fly. Delaying it will require to store results in a list that will need several GB of RAM. That said, your "mapper" work-around is sensible, I came up with something similar.

Comment: It sounds like your stats calculation is work that needs to happen either way.  If you don't want it to happen in parallel with the result generation and you don't want to defer it to the end, you can make a forwarding generator. It would get a result from the true iterator, updates stats, and yield the result.  You then pass the forwarding generator into pool.imap instead of the true iterator.